# Weird space in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

we are using angularJs. Now in ng-repeat we using the code to generate ids(we are using ngClipboard  to copy data to clipboard).

`<div ng-bind-html="model.property" id="specialProp-{{$index}}"></div>`

Expected result should be

`<div ng-bind-html="reference.bibliography" id="refBib-1"></div>`

But sometimes it is

`<div ng-bind-html="reference.bibliography" id="refBib-    1"></div>`
Why this empty space,and what I can do to mitigate it?

Comment: I'm curious why you are creating ID's using your ng-repeat

Comment: You sure there are no whitespaces in the data? You can use .trim() maybe.

Comment: @Malkus- We are using ng-clipboard as I said and it needs data-target id selector hence that why.

Comment: are using ng-repeat's native $index or creating your own?

Comment: `$index` is ng-repeat value, and it's just an integer, highly unlikely it comes from angular itself, I'd like to see more of the code to understand it

Comment: try to use {{ +$index }}

Comment: Based on your code I would actually recommend the following `data-clipboard-text="{{reference.bibliography}}"` on your button to do the copy.

Comment: @Malkus-Issue is that there are multiple references hence that's why I couldnt use your answer.